# Can't add new System ODBC to PostgreSQL db

Tags: windows-10, postgresql, odbc

I am working on HP 64-bit machine on Windows 10. 
Already have a working System ODBC connection to a "Production" PosgreSQL db, it is postgreSQL ANSI(x64), using it for a while now.

The problem is, when I want to add a new System connection (to our "Backoffice" db, also postgreSQL), clicking **ADD**-> **postgreSQL ANSI(x64)** -> **Finish** opens up the window with the complete configuration of the existing, "Production" connection, not a blank window.

If I fill in the "Backoffice" credentials there, it deletes the "Production" info. I don't get any error message, the connection just switches to "Backoffice".

Adding literally any other type of data source opens a blank window and allows me to create a new connection. 
That includes creating a **USER** DSN for PostgreSQL, but that doesn't solve my problem, I need the second connection to also be a **SYSTEM** one.

Am I doing something wrong?
Never had this situation for SQL dbs so don't know how to even begin to solve; any info highly appreciated. Thanks!